# What is the fedora equivalent of libusb-1.0, libc6:i386, and lib32ncurses5?

Tags: fedora, dnf

I'm trying to play around with a STM32F407G microcontroller, and I've been following along this tutorial online.

The instructor of the course says that ubuntu users need to install the following packages: `libusb-1.0`, `libc6:i386`, and `lib32ncurses5`.

However, I can't find them when I do `dnf install`. I'm a bit new to fedora, and so I'm wondering whether there's an equivalent to these packages on fedora?

Comment: Why does he want you to install 32-bit libraries? Why does he want you to install these at all?

Comment: If you attempt to install the libraries themselves then the correct packages will be found.

Comment: @MichaelHampton To be honest, I'm very new to microcontrollers, so I'm not too sure. On windows, there was a download directly from the microcontroller vendor's site, but apparently on linux we don't need it other than the packages he had listed.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams But which libraries do I need to install? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: So what is the next step? All of this is supposed to happen in some sort of context. Where is the tutorial? Where are the rest of the instructions?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - well, these installations are for allowing me to interact with the microcontroller using my PC (via a usb cable). For windows, the vendor provided some file, but apparently only these packages are needed for linux (or atleast ubuntu).
I can give you the tutorial link (a udemy course), but not sure if that would be helpful.  
Once the driver is set up, it continues on with the actual embedded development tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 32bits libraries

```
# dnf search [name]
# dnf install glibc.i686 libusb.i686 ncurses-compat-libs.i686
```

Note : The ncurses system version is 6.x . `ncurses-compat-libs` provides :

```
./usr/lib/libform.so.5
./usr/lib/libform.so.5.9
./usr/lib/libformw.so.5
./usr/lib/libformw.so.5.9
./usr/lib/libmenu.so.5
./usr/lib/libmenu.so.5.9
./usr/lib/libmenuw.so.5
./usr/lib/libmenuw.so.5.9
./usr/lib/libncurses++.so.5
./usr/lib/libncurses++.so.5.9
./usr/lib/libncurses++w.so.5
./usr/lib/libncurses++w.so.5.9
./usr/lib/libncurses.so.5
./usr/lib/libncurses.so.5.9
./usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5
./usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5.9
./usr/lib/libpanel.so.5
./usr/lib/libpanel.so.5.9
./usr/lib/libpanelw.so.5
./usr/lib/libpanelw.so.5.9
./usr/lib/libtic.so.5
./usr/lib/libtic.so.5.9
./usr/lib/libtinfo.so.5
./usr/lib/libtinfo.so.5.9
```